# Why is the recent questions feed showing code?

Tags: support, feed

When I clicked on `recent questions feed` on bottom of the site, I was navigated to the `/feeds` endpoint; where I can see the code.

I don't know if this a bug, or does the page always show such code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional. This is an [Atom feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(Web_standard)) (also mistakenly called [RSS feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) - that's actually a different protocol, but it's using the same icon) and if you have an appropriate program/app (a so-called 'reader') it will organize all feeds you subscribe to (from Stack Exchange or other websites). If you don't have a reader, your browser will offer to download it or show it as 'code', because in essence it's 'just' an XML file (though it is a [specialized version of XML](https://www.w3.org/2005/Atom)).